# Can you use your passport between other countries if you are banned from leaving your home country?

Tags: air-travel, passports

Someone who is banned from leaving the country gave me some information that's surprising.

He is banned because he's a witness in a trial. Not sure when his ban will be lifted.

This is not a country known for human rights.

Anyway.

1. He says his passport allows him to travel freely between countries even if he has a ban. For example, if he was in Japan, he'd be able to fly to anywhere except his home country. He also said that even members of terrorist groups are in the same position. They can use their passports as long as they're outside of the country.

This makes no sense to me. I asked him why the government isn't cancelling their passports.

2. He said that in that case these people would have much easier time getting a refugee status from European countries. I think a few European countries are funding the said terrorist organization. So he kind of makes sense
3. He also said if he illegally crosses borders to another country from his home country, he can use his passport to fly to countries with no issues.

I was under the impression that he'd be deported back to his home country if he tries to use his passport in another country. I thought this is true especially for members of terrorist groups. But he's insisting that's not the case.

Is he right?

I find it weird that a government thinks someone is a terrorist but then lets him maintain his travel freedom.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140346/discussion-on-question-by-user131834-can-you-use-your-passport-between-other-cou).

Answer (score 3):

This depends a lot on the specific countries involve so there is no "one size fits all answer"

> He says his passport allows him to travel freely between countries even if he has a ban.

That's generally correct. Unless the country you are trying to enter shares a data base with your home country, the border control will not know about your ban. They also might not care. They are not enforcers for other countries unless both countries have very close relationships. If your passports meets the travel requirements, you can travel with it.

> ... these people would have easier time getting a passport from European countries.

Highly unlikely. You may be able to get refugee status and ask for asylum but that doesn't give a you passport. That's a long and arduous route.

> I think A few European countries are funding the said terrorist organization.

What the heck is that supposed to mean ?

> He also said if he illegally crosses borders to another country from his home country, he can use his passport to fly to countries with no issues.

Depends. Most countries don't care if you illegally leave another country. However, they deeply care whether you illegally enter their own country. Crossing a border contains two steps: leaving country A and entering country B. Doing the second step illegally is likely to get you in trouble: Unless there are special exemptions in place, you would get deported and banned from country B.

If you manage to legally enter B (by presenting yourself at a point of entry) and you are admitted, you may indeed be allowed to travel onwards with your existing passport. As long as it's not revoked or invalidated, it's a valid travel document

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140347/discussion-on-answer-by-hilmar-can-you-use-your-passport-between-other-countries).

Answer (score 2):

In general only three things are going to be relevant to the visiting country, assuming you have gone through all the processes normally required to get admittance:

1. Is your passport valid - specifically has it been cancelled by the home country. If it has been cancelled then they will not let you in. Normally when a country officially cancels a passport they make you surrender it. Neither of these seem to have happened in your case. Note that invalidating a passport is rare. If a country doesn't want you to travel then they simply take your passport from you. That's much easier than telling every country in the world that your passport is invalid.
2. Has your home country asked for you to be arrested and extradited. This can happen - for example if you are suspected of a crime and you attempt to flee then your home country might ask any country you visit to arrest you and return you. Your passport is fairly irrelevant here, as the arrest notice says "arrest this person" not "arrest the person with this passport", since criminals have been known to use fake or alternative passports. Whether the visiting country complies is dependent on a whole lot of things.
3. Has your home country persuaded the visiting country that they should not welcome you. They can do this without formally charging you with a crime - it just involves convincing the visiting country not to let you in. Countries can deny entry to anyone if they think admitting them would not be in their interests. This has to be done for each country you visit. Again the passport is only peripherally important, since they want you to be excluded whatever passport you are using.

If none of those things happen then the visiting country is unlikely to prevent you entering. That doesn't mean you aren't violating the laws of your home country.

Comment: Thank you. When he wants to enter a country, his passport number is entered into a system which connects to the relevant country's database. That's how they check if its cancelled, right? Another question: Is it difficult to cancel a passport for a government? Maybe there are international laws that make this difficult

Comment: I don't know the details, whether it is done by interrogating the home country database (I suspect not since country immigrations don't like to be dependent on other countries) or by the home country informing other countries that certain passports are cancelled.

Comment: If country immigrations don't like to be dependent on other countries, how can they know a passport is cancelled or valid?

Comment: I meant "don't like to have to talk to a foreign database every time a person tries to enter". If the home country sends a list of invalidated passports (daily? weekly?) then they will likely pay attention and record the fact in their own databases.

Comment: Oh ok, makes sense. Yeah the system might be down. Nobody has time to wait for that. I wonder where I can ask my other question: "Is it difficult to cancel a passport for a government? Maybe there are international laws that make this difficult" I really don't get why this government isn't cancelling passports of people they categorize as terrorists. And I want to understand how this works

Comment: The normal approach when a country doesn't want you to leave is that they take your passport from you. That's a much easier means of prevention than invalidating it. Invalidating is pretty rare.

Comment: Also please explain why you talked about terrorism when asked about refugees?

Comment: Interesting. Why is it easier? I'd say its more difficult because you have to find the person and the person might be overseas. But passports have unique identifiers in them, which lets you query if the passport is still considered valid by the issuing country. No? So all the country has to do is to set the passport to invalid, then when the passport holder travels, he can't go anywhere other than his home country. Why do you think invalidating is pretty rare?

Comment: This country's terrorists are another country's (some EU ones in this case) potential refugees. So, the guy was talking about them. "I have a ban from leaving the country but I can use my passport overseas. Even terrorists can use their passports..." and then get into details like I wrote in the post. Maybe he's full of sh.t, maybe not. idk

Comment: If someone has been reasonably accused of terrorism then they fall under category 2 in my answer. There are few enough of them that the country accusing them says "Watch out for this person and arrest them if they enter your country". It's very different from your friend's supposed case, and it doesn't depend on whether their passport is valid or not.

Comment: "When a country doesn't want you to leave is that they take your passport from you. That's a much easier means of prevention than invalidating it" -- Why is it easier? I'd say its more difficult because you have to find the person and the person might be overseas. But passports have unique identifiers in them, which lets the border agent query if the passport is still considered valid by the issuing country. No? So all the country has to do is to set the passport to invalid, then when the passport holder travels, he can't go anywhere other than his home country

Comment: Let us take this to chat: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140349/invalidating-a-passport